# How to use timer in flutter app for changing data?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using shared preferences to store the token, email, username and other user details when a user logs in using firebase authentication. The firebase token expires in every one hour so I need to refresh the token on the basis of when the user has returned to the app which I am doing in `getCurrentUser()` function below. I want to know that if a user has logged in my app, used it for 5 minutes or so and then close the application, will that timer function would still be listening and call the function after the timeout or not?
If it doesn't do so then How can I achieve checking this?

```
void checkTokenValidity(int time) {
Timer(Duration(seconds: time), () async {
  print('token timed out');
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('token', 'expired');
  prefs.remove("currentUser");
});
}

Future<String> getCurrentUser() async {
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final String currentToken = prefs.getString('token');
final String cuser = prefs.getString('currentUser');
print("current: $cuser");
if (cuser != null && currentToken != 'expired') {
  print('signed in and $currentToken');
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String token = prefs.getString('token');
  String uid = prefs.getString('userId');
  String email = prefs.getString('userEmail');
  String photo = prefs.getString('photo');
  _authenticatedUser =
      User(email: email, id: uid, token: token, photo: photo);
  return 'success';
} else if (currentToken == 'expired') {
  print('token is expired');
  final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
  var token = await user.getIdToken();
  prefs.setString('token', token);
  String uid = prefs.getString('userId');
  String email = prefs.getString('userEmail');
  String photo = prefs.getString('photo');
  _authenticatedUser =
      User(id: uid, email: email, token: token, photo: photo);
  checkTokenValidity(3600);
  return 'token';
} else {
  print('user is null');
  return null;
}
}
```

In my authentication function which is not here, I have called `checkTokenValidity(3600)` just after the user successfully logs in.

I have also tried using `FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();` but that also didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Why are you storing these details? The Firebase Authentication client already persists the user's authentication state between app restarts, so you can just look if up with `await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` where needed.

Comment: That's right but it is actually not a problem here and it's not working, the main problem is does the timer function listen even after closing the app?

Comment: If your question is about Firebase Authentication, you might want to remove those parts from your question. This makes it much more likely that someone can/will help. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is there any way that I can add firebase authentication in flutter app which automatically refreshes token, use google sign in, means everything which is pre-built like it is there for kotlin and java?

Comment: Firebase Authentication automatically refreshes the token under the hood. You don't need to do anything for that.

Comment: `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` is not working in firebase auth plugin and it is returning null everytime. Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: I'm surprised that it wouldn't work, since I've used it multiple times in the past to detect the restored user auth state. Can you check if there's any logging output showing that might be relevant?

Comment: Maybe it's because of a bug in flutter's firebase_auth package. Anyways, I found a different way of using the difference in date-time stamps to refresh token so it is working now.

Comment: Good go hear Harshit. If you post your workaround as an answer, others can potentially benefit from that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You went the wrong way. The right way is to add error handler on 401 (Unauthorized) error and handle it by refreshing token and retrying the same query.